# Parsing node labels to prossibly extract clauses in a syntactic tree

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

As an example I have the following parse tree from the Stanford Parser. How do I extract the labels like S and SBAR to eventually extract clauses. I tried a small piece of code (which is obviously incorrect) as a starting point, using different Tree methods, but nothing gave me the desired results.

Code:

```
for (Tree subtree: parseTree.getLeaves()){
            if (subtree.label().equals("S")||subtree.label().equals("SBAR"))
                System.out.println("SUBTREE:::"+"\t"+ subtree.getLeaves());
        }
```

Parse Tree:

```
(ROOT
      (S
        (NP
          (NP (DT A) (NNP Bristol) (NN hospital))
          (SBAR
            (WHNP (WDT that))
            (S
              (VP (VBD retained)
                (NP
                  (NP (DT the) (NNS hearts))
                  (PP (IN of)
                    (NP
                      (NP (CD 300) (NNS children))
                      (SBAR
                        (WHNP (WP who))
                        (S
                          (VP (VBD died)
                            (PP (IN in)
                              (NP (JJ complex) (NNS operations)))))))))))))
        (VP (VBD behaved)
          (ADVP (IN in) (DT a))
          ('' '')
          (S
            (VP (VBG cavalier) ('' '')
              (NP (NN fashion))))
          (PP (IN towards)
            (NP (DT the) (NNS parents))))
        (. .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code for going through a tree and finding the `S` and `SBAR`:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;

import java.util.*;

public class FindSAndSBARInTreeExample {

  public static void findSAndSBAR(Tree tree) {
    for (Tree subtree : tree.getChildrenAsList()) {
      if (subtree.label().value().equals("S") || subtree.label().value().equals("SBAR")) {
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println(subtree.yieldWords());
      }
      findSAndSBAR(subtree);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
    // use faster shift reduce parser
    props.setProperty("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
    props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "100");
    // set up Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // build annotation for a review
    Annotation annotation =
        new Annotation(
            "A Bristol hospital that retained the hearts of 300 children who died in " +
                "complex operations behaved in a \"cavalier fashion\" towards the parents");
    // annotate
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    // get tree
    Tree tree =
        annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0).get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
    System.out.println(tree);
    // find S and SBAR
    findSAndSBAR(tree);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use Tregex.  Here is some sample code:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;

public class TregexUsageExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // Spanish example
    Annotation annotation =
        new Annotation(
            "A Bristol hospital that retained the hearts of 300 children who died in " +
                "complex operations behaved in a \"cavalier fashion\" towards the parents");
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    // get first sentence
    CoreMap firstSentence = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0);
    Tree firstSentenceTree = firstSentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
    // use Tregex to match
    String SorSBARPattern = "/SBAR|^S$/";
    TregexPattern SorSBARTregexPattern = TregexPattern.compile(SorSBARPattern);
    TregexMatcher SorSBARTregexMatcher = SorSBARTregexPattern.matcher(firstSentenceTree);
    while (SorSBARTregexMatcher.find()) {
      SorSBARTregexMatcher.getMatch().pennPrint();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In fact I would recommend using Tregex over my original answer.